# Removing Exact Duplicate records(same id as well) but keep one

Tags: mysql

I need a query which will delete all the records from the table which has exactly same row(even same id) but keep only one.

Here is my database structure:

```
      [ ID      STATUS   ] 
       '1', 'New Request'
       '1', 'New Request'
       '2', 'Old Request'
```

A query which will delete the first or maybe the second row but keep one record. So, there can be 3 , 4 or maybe more identical records but i have to delete all and keep only one. Please, assist me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql has some insights

Comment: @xeo my cases has duplicate id's as well. And i also have to keep one and delete the rest.

Comment: it supports that - basically you forgot to add a unique key and that post describes how to correct it using several options.

Comment: Just a side note, You can avoid such situations in the first place by making the ID column unique

Comment: I reject the premise of the question. If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't have a table.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how big your table is, you could copy all distinct records into a temp table, truncate the original table, then copy back into the original:

```
CREATE TEMPORY TABLE tmp AS SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table;
TRUNCATE table;
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tmp;
```

Comment: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

Try following set of queries:

Select distinct [id], [status] into temptable from table

Go

Delete from table

Go

Insert into table select [id], [status] from temptable

Go

Drop table temptable

Go

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `Go`, that MSSQL.